# Help with $\int \frac{1}{(1-t^2)t^2} \, dt$

Tags: integration, solution-verification

$$\int \frac{1}{(1-t^2)t^2} \, dt$$

By using partial fractions I get:

$$\frac{1}{(1-t)(1+t)t^2} = \frac{A}{t} + \frac{B}{t^2} + \frac{C}{t+1} + \frac{D}{1-t}$$
$$1 = t^3 (-A-C+D) + t^2 (-B+C+D) + At+ B$$
$$-A-C+D = 0$$
$$-B+C+D=0$$
$$A=0$$
$$B=1$$

So, $A=0, B=1, C=\frac{1}{2}, D = \frac{1}{2}$
Then by replacing the variables with the results we get:

$$\int \frac{1}{(1-t^2)t^2} \, dt = \int \frac{1}{t^2} \, dt + \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{t+1} \, dt + \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1}{1-t} \, dt$$
$$- \frac{1}{t} + C + \frac{1}{2} \ln|t+1| + C + \frac{1}{2} \ln|1-t| + C$$
$$- \frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{2} \ln|t+1| + \frac{1}{2} \ln|1-t| + C$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Partial fraction decompostion is not 100% correct. You got the $1/t^2$ term wrong. It should be $-1/t$.

Comment: @vitamind could you tell me what's wrong with it please?

Comment: I must apologize. After checking it one more time it became clear to me that I was mistakenly talking about the integral of $\frac{1}{(t^2-1)t}$. Sorry.

Comment: given @J.G.’s answer, it looks like you’re only missing a minus sign in front of $+\frac{1}{2}\ln|1-t|$, thus should be $-\frac{1}{2}\ln|1-t|$ where you can use the sub. $u=1-t$ and $du=-dt$ to get this answer

Comment: the last logarithm should have minus in front, otherwise you did a good job

Comment: Substitute $u = t^2$ and then use partial fractions. Once you've found the decomposition, you may substitute back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that$$\int\frac{1}{t^2(1-t^2)}dt=\int\left(\frac{1}{t^2}+\frac{1}{1-t^2}\right)dt=-\frac1t+\frac12\ln\left|\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right|+K,$$where the locally constant function $K$ can change values either side of $t=\pm1$, so its values can be different for $t<-1,\,t\in(-1,\,1),\,t>1$. (I've called it $K$ rather than $C$ since $C$ is already a coefficient in your partial fractions calculation.) As @Vasya noted, the only issue is your $\ln|1-t|$ coefficient.

Answer (score 5):

We may utilize $$\dfrac1{t^2(1-t^2)}=\dfrac{(1-t^2)+t^2}{t^2(1-t^2)}=\dfrac1{t^2}+\dfrac1{1-t^2}$$

Finally $$\dfrac1{1-t^2}=\dfrac{1+t+1-t}{2(1-t)(1+t)}=?$$

Comment: Maybe im stupid, but I understood all answers except this one.

Comment: @GreasyLlama, Please find the edited post

Comment: oh lol thanks a lot